# Shell script error using wget

Tags: bash, shell, wget

```
#!/bin/bash
download=$(wget -qO- $url)
echo "$download"
```

I made a simple bash script that is supposed to download a picture from a url. However this does not work, I keep getting the error bash command subsittution: ignored null byte in input.

How can i fix this?

Comment: What is the content of `$url`?

Comment: I'm using http://roblabcam.hiof.no/now.jpg . But i believe this page is not accessible unless you have a vpn.

Comment: How does your script know you want to use this URL? Do you export it before you invoke your script?

Comment: instead of $url i typed in roblabcam.hiof.no/now.jpg

Comment: Why are you trying to save the contents of a binary file to a variable in the first place? `echo "$download"` isn't going to *display* the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wget -O-` prints you picture in binary form. Then your script tries to execute this, because you put it in `$()`, which is the source of your error message.

What you need to do is pass the binary stream of the picture you get from wget to a program that can interpret it. For example, you can use **feh**(1).

`wget -qO- http://apache.org/images/asf_logo.gif | feh -`

[1] https://feh.finalrewind.org/